Jetbrains Gateway has a very high ping/latency
I'm using PyCharm / Jetbrains Gateway with an EC2 instance and I'm getting terrible latency, like 2-4 seconds. How do I fix this?

I was able to resolve the issue by closing the project and shutting down the remote IDE instance, then restarting PyCharm, restarting the remote IDE instance, and reconnecting to it. I got the idea from this comment in the Jetbrains issue tracker:

Usually after a restart of the application it is fine.

